# Is there a way to restart the tutorial in Age of Wonders: Planetfall?

Tags: age-of-wonders-planetfall

Is there any way to restart the game tutorial without finishing it first? I got about halfway through (I presume) and want to restart it, but the only option I see on the main menu is "Continue".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a saved file in my c:\users\*username*\documents\paradox interactive\age of wonders planetfall\saves.  Once I removed the files in here, the tutorial reappeared for a selection on the main screen.

Answer (score 2):

I've looked up a playthrough, and it appears like the tutorial is really just the first mission of the single player campaign, so you should be able to restart it through the campaign screen.

Comment: I'm afraid to test this since I've now finished the tutorial, and am not sure if starting a new campaign erases progress in the old one, but this seems to fit since even after completing the tutorial, I have only a "Continue" option.